# Angular $window listener remove or not?

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular's $window inside directive to listen for resize. Here is my code:

```
var resizeWindow = _.debounce(function(){},500);
$window.onresize = resizeWindow;
```

Is there any need to remove the listener on scope destroy? Or it will be removed by angular?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There **is** a need to remove the pointer, since the directive doesn't "know" you have attached a method to the window service (since the window wrapper doesn't share a scope with the window) and therefore can't remove the pointer.

Comment: Thanks! And  if I use angular.element($window).bind(...)?

Comment: You still have to.. For the same reason - the directive's scope can't possibly know about the method you've attached. Just curios, why do you need the window resize event? (can't it be something accomplished with CSS?)

Comment: I can not do it from css I need to rerender everything. anyways thanks!